# Where do I get a new PDA?

Tags: space-station-13

If my PDA has been stolen, what's the procedure for getting a new one? Is there any place where I can pick one up myself, or do I need to request it from someone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I frequently play Head of Personnel and get asked for a new one ALL the time...but sadly I think you're out of luck if you lose the one you're given.

What you CAN do, if you can find someone else's PDA and they no longer need it, is put your own ID card in and update the PDA info.  It will then become yours.

If the PDA you've found does not match the job you have, you'll need to find an appropriate PDA cartridge to plug in and update with as well. The Head of Personnel can also re-paint your PDA to look like the appropriate PDA (on some servers), though you'll probably need to explain what you're doing with someone else's PDA.

As far as I know though, there's no way to get a new one if yours is lost, stolen or blow up.

---

**Edit**: Someone mentioned to me that our server (/tg/) actually has a box of PDAs on the bridge itself, so if you ask the HoP for one from the bridge, he should be able to provide one.